# I am getting this error in my R code "Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Failure when receiving data from the peer "

Tags: mysql, r, google-bigquery

I had written code in R to get data from bigquery and write into MySQL. My code working properly from last few month but now i am getting this error.

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
  Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

it writes incomplete data in mysql.

i had written this code.

```
sql <- 'SELECT * FROM[XXXXXX-XXXXXX:catalog_output.catalog_dynamic];'
catalog_dynamic <- query_exec(sql, project, destination_table =
"XXXXXXXX.XXXXXX", default_dataset = NULL,page_size = 100,
max_pages = Inf, warn = TRUE,create_disposition = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED", 
write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE")
```